# Embed XML from file into RMD

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I have an XML file (`SOME.XML`), the contents of which I would like to embed in an `.RMD` document.

If I was content with having the XML reside directly within the `.RMD`, I'm aware that I could simply do:

````
```xml
---some xml here---
```
````

My embarassing attempts so far are:

````
```{xml code=readr::read_file('SOME.XML')}
```
````

...which failed as there is no XML engine.

I have also tried:

`````
````{r results='asis'}
cat('```xml')
cat(readr::read_file('SOME.XML'))
cat('```')
````
`````

...for which, although the knitting completes, the output is not at all correct.

**Is this possible?** (No doubt there is some trick here that I am missing!)

If needed, I *could* have a pre-knit stage where the content of the XML file is substituted in before subsequently passing a modified version of the `.RMD` to `rmarkdown::render`. However, I'd like to avoid this if possible.

---

**Update:**

Using `readLines` as proposed by the answer is complaining about `...incomplete final line found on 'SOME.XML'`. Using `readr::read_file()` avoids this for me. For my particular project, I am now using:

````
```xml
`r readr::read_file("SOME.XML")`
```
````

**Thank you to @user2554330 for the elegant solution!**

Comment: What do you want? Extract some data from xml and build a table?

Comment: Your second approach looks pretty close.  What goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

````
```xml
`r paste(readLines("SOME.XML"), collapse = "\n")`
```
````

The idea is to put the XML into inline R code.  I think knitr ignores the chunk wrappers because they aren't in the `{xml ...` format it looks for, but it will see the inline code and expand it.  Then Pandoc will handle the formatting.

Here's how to modify your approach to get it to work:

`````
````{r results='asis', echo = FALSE}
cat('```xml\n')
cat(readr::read_file('SOME.XML'), sep = "\n")
cat('\n```\n')
````
`````

Comment: You nailed it... I've had to tweak it slightly as `readLines` was complaining about `....incomplete final line found on 'SOME.XML'`. I will show my revised code in my original question. Thank you!

Comment: Given your first solution, there is no need to use my work around any more. Those top 3x lines do the trick.

Comment: There's an advantage to your original approach:  you could write a function that did it all with a call like `insertCode(file = "SOME.XML", language = "xml")`.

Comment: Ah ok... **I'm guessing the function call would still need to be wrapped in a `{r ...}` block?**

Comment: Yes, or the inline markup like I used in my first approach.

Comment: Understood... Thank you for confirming.